# Replacing a dynamic image on flex

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript-3, flash-builder

I am creating an image dynamically on flex. This images changes (as in changes image source) when the user clicks on it. Images are PNG format and I replace it with this code:

```
img.source = PATH_TO_IMAGE;
```

The problem with this is when I replace the image is it is not smooth even if you set the image property to smoothBitmapContent.

Is there a way to smoothen images when you are trying to replace the source?

Thanks in Advance

EDIT: I would like to add that the image is a round button (like the ones used in bullets)

Comment: Are both images the same size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check that it's not a scaling issue - make sure scaleX and scaleY are 1.0 and not something insane like 1.0000011

Comment: actually I'm not resizing it, and I'm pretty sure that the size is not being touched. Both images are of the same size.

Comment: check the parent size them. can you upload an image of the problem somewhere?

Comment: I think I have solved the problem already by using a Loader ( e.g. imageLoader.load(new URLRequest(PAHT_TO_IMAGE)); ) and from here I have converted it to bitmap and smoothen it. Still I don't know why doing it directly affects the image. Thanks anyway, divilly

Comment: The image is distorted because you are adjusting the width and height or scale out of proportion. Somewhere in your code (most-likely a container element) you are stretching the image.

Comment: actually I did check my code and yes at some point I was turning my whole app to FullScreen and that makes it distorted. Instead I was able to convert the image to bitmap and apply smoothing before placing it to the image source by following this http://ntt.cc/2008/03/09/tips-three-ways-to-load-an-image-file-in-flex.html (the second way). This way images are smoother.